# How can I define something belonging to another namespace in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a clj file using a certain namespace and I wish to define something belonging to another namespace, so I do :

```
(def  other.namespace/name-of-something "value")
```

: but when I do this I get the result :

```
java.lang.Exception: Can't refer to qualified var that doesn't exist
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you'll need to ensure that the namespace exists via a call to `create-ns`:

```
(create-ns 'other.namespace)
```

Then, you can use the `intern` function to add definitions to that namespace:

```
(intern 'other.namespace 'name-of-something "value")
```

You can confirm this is present with a call to `(ns-interns 'other.namespace)`.